# Iterate lists at intervals based on list values

Tags: python

I've been trying to accomplish this in a few different ways and just can't quite seem to get it to work for me.
I'm trying to iterate over a list in blocks, where the first index value is an integer for how many elements are in the first block. After that, another integer with n elements, and another, etc.

Example:

```
test = [3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'd', 'e', 3, 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I want to read 3, pull 'a', 'b', 'c' from the list and perform some operation on them.
Then return to the list at 2, pull 'd', 'e' - more operations, etc.
Or even just using the integers to split into sub-lists would work.

I'm thinking list slicing with updated [start:stop:step] variables but am having trouble pulling it together.

Any suggestions?
Can only use the standard Python library.

Comment: read the value in loop and if it is number slice it and jumps to next index

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generator to iterate lazily on the parts of the list:

```
test = [3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'd', 'e', 3, 'f', 'g', 'h']
​
def parts(lst):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(lst):
        part_length = lst[idx]
        yield lst[idx+1: idx + part_length + 1 ]
        idx += part_length+1
        
for part in parts(test):
    print(part)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e']
['f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input structure is always like this you can do the following:

```
result = [test[i:i+j] for i, j in enumerate(test, 1) if isinstance(j, int)]
print(result)

# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on the list makes this super simple. Just grab the next item which tells you how much more to grab next, and so on until the end of the list:

```py
test = [3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 'd', 'e', 3, 'f', 'g', 'h']

it = iter(test)
for num in it:
    print(", ".join(next(it) for _ in range(num)))
```

which prints:

```
a, b, c
d, e
f, g, h
```

---

You can also convert this to a list if you need to save the result:

```
>>> it = iter(test)
>>> [[next(it) for _ in range(num)] for num in it]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
```